# React Uncontrolled Form - null value Jest Test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

When I'm testing an uncontrolled form via Jest my `onChange` handler receives the new values but when I confirm the value it returns `Null`.

I put together a test here - https://github.com/timarney/react-formtest

Do I have to use either a `Controlled Form` or `ReactLink`?
http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html

Comment: Here's a screen of the failing test.

https://github.com/timarney/react-formtest/blob/master/form-fail.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3151

`var node = el.getDOMNode();
node.value = 'new value';
TestUtils.Simulate.change(node);
expect(node.value).toEqual('new value');`